# Which timeframe is covered by the Disk tab in Activity Monitor from macOS

Tags: macos

Activity Monitor has a *Disk* tab which shows some IO stats.

What is the time period these stats cover, especially *Bytes Written/Read* (per Application) and *Data read/written* (overall)?

My guess would be time since mount of the Disk, which would be the System uptime in most cases, but I can't find any confirmation about this in [the official documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464).

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of stats. What exactly do you mean? The graph? Or the other numbers?

Comment: I got more specific with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 minutes.

Tested by simple empiricism.
Open window, note time, find something not too engrossing to do until the window is full, note time again, subtract a from b.

*After original question was edited...*
I assumed you meant the central graph data display window at the bottom.
Everything else is 'since boot'.